# Dismiss non-cancelable dialog on fragment backPress - Android

Tags: android, dialog, onbackpressed

I have a Navigation drawer activity and many fragments that I reach via the nav drawer.

In some of these fragments, I show a dialog which says "Loading.." while background tasks are happening.

Now I've made my dialogs not-cancellable by `dialog.setCancelable(false)` so that the user doesn't accidentally dismiss it by clicking anywhere on the screen. This makes it un-cancelable even when the phone back button is pressed.

This is the code for my dialog -

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_dialog);
    ((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_message)).setText("Loading ...");

    dialog.setCancelable(false);     
    dialog.show();
```

I need to write code to dismiss the loading dialog and go to the previous fragment when the phone back button is pressed while on any fragment.

Can somebody help me out? Mostly I need implementing backPress specific to a fragment. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use  `getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();`

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 10):

Remove your code line :

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

and put this one and try

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

With this your dialog will not cancel if user accidentally touch on the screen, but if user press back button then it will cancel

Answer (score 9):

It's simple as this

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

please put the following code where you are initializing the `alertDialogbuilder`.

```
    alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alertDialogBuilder.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```